# Данные не добавляются в BehaviorSubject и ReplaySubject

Tags: angular2, rxjs

Здравствуйте!
У меня имеется `login.component.ts`. Вот его код:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

import { AuthenticationService } from "../services/authentication.service"; 

    @Component({
        selector: "login",
        templateUrl: "app/login/login.component.html",
        styleUrls: ['../../style.css'],
        providers: [AuthenticationService]
    })

    export class LoginComponent{

        constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService){ }

        login(value: any){
            this.authenticationService.login(value);
        }
    }
```

Заполненные данные в форме отправляются в сервис `authentication.service.ts`. Вот его код:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { AppConfig } from '../app.config';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { User } from '../models/user.model';

import { JwtService } from './jwt.service';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    constructor(private http: Http,
        private appConfig: AppConfig,
        private jwtService: JwtService,
        private apiService: ApiService,
        private router: Router) { }

    public currentUserSubject: Subject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(new User());
    public isAuthenticatedSubject: Subject<any> = new ReplaySubject(1);

    getUser() {
        return this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
    }

    getIsAuthenctication(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.isAuthenticatedSubject.asObservable();
    }

    checkAuth() {
        if (this.jwtService.getToken()) {
            this.apiService.getUserByToken().subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.setAuth(data.user)
                },
                err => {
                    this.logout();
                }
            )
        } else {
            this.logout();
        }
    }

    setAuth(user: User) {
        this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
        this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(true);
        this.jwtService.setToken(user.token);
        console.log(this.currentUserSubject);
        console.log(this.isAuthenticatedSubject);
    }

    login(user: User) {
        this.http.post(this.appConfig.urlServer + "/auth/login", user)
            .map((res) => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .catch((error) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
            .subscribe(
            (data) => {
                this.currentUserSubject.next(data.user);
                this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(true);
                this.jwtService.setToken(data.user.token);
                console.log(this.isAuthenticatedSubject);
                console.log(this.currentUserSubject);
                this.router.navigate(['']);
            },
            (err) => console.error("loadAllPackages: ERROR"),
            () => console.log("loadAllPackages: always")
            );
    }

    logout() {
        this.jwtService.removeToken();
        this.currentUserSubject.next(new User());
        this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(false);
    }

}
```

В currentUserSubject добавляю данные о пользователе, который успешно вошел.
В isAuthenticatedSubject добавляю true, если пользователь успешно вошел, и false, если он не вошел.

Если в локальном хранилище будет находится token, то currentUserSubject и isAuthenticatedSubject не пустые. Если же в локальном хранилище пустота, то ни данные, ни булевское значение не добавляются в currentUserSubject и isAuthenticatedSubject соответственно.

В чем может быть причина ?

Comment: Я решил данную проблему. Необходимо убрать `[providers]` в компоненте `login.component.ts`